# Prompt on exit in PyQt application

Tags: python, pyqt, exit

Is there any way to promt user to exit the gui-program written in Python?

Something like "Are you sure you want to exit the program?"

I'm using PyQt.

Comment: Look at the "Message Box" section of [this part of the PyQt4 tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/firstprograms/).

Comment: Look at the "Message Box" section of [this part of the PyQt4 tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/firstprograms/). *(answer from [las3rjock](http://stackoverflow.com/users/94732/las3rjock))*

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes. You need to override the default close behaviour of the QWidget representing your application so that it doesn't immediately accept the event. The basic structure you want is something like this:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):

    quit_msg = "Are you sure you want to exit the program?"
    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', 
                     quit_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

    if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

The PyQt [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/) mentioned by [las3rjock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414781/prompt-on-exit-in-pyqt-application/1414828#1414828) has a nice discussion of this. Also check out the links from the [PyQt page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) at Python.org, in particular the [official reference](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/), to learn more about events and how to handle them.

Comment: How to set "yes" and "no" to be in some other language? If my message is, for example in German, I want "ja" and "nicht" instead of "yes" and "no".

Comment: worked for me out of the box (without any modification needed)!

Comment: `QtWidgets.QMessageBox` not `QtGui.QMessageBox` with Qt5