# Call a function when user closes app ( pyQt5 )

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to have my app save data before closing itself. I can have the user use the quit button (I made myself) that is connected to a function. But I don't know how to call the function when the user closes the app native close button.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to call a function when the user uses the close button as mentioned in the screenshot above? Thank you for your time in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

[This question has 2 answers that can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832880/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-function-right-before-a-pyqt-application-ends)

Most common way would be:

```
class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    #...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print "closing PyQtTest"
        self.SaveSettings()
        # report_session()
```

Or  [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module of the standard Python.

Comment: It gives me this error: "AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QWidget'". Even though I have imported: "from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets".

Comment: Updated answer to `QtWidgets.QWidget`

Comment: It still did not work. I close the app and the print function doesn't get executed.

Comment: @AliHaiderSultani are you by any chance editing a pyuic generated file?