# pyqt graceful logout my app when user signs off

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, session-management

When my app is running, if the user logs off I would like to pop up a window displaying some info and confirming the logout

```
class MyApp(QtWidgets.QApplication):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.commitDataRequest.connect(lambda manager: self.commitData(manager))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QSessionManager)
    def commitData(self, manager):
        print 'shutdown'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qapplication = MyApp(sys.argv)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False) #interaction through tray icon
    application.exec_()
```

The issue is that it's not going into that slot method.

My app does not have a main window, its interfaces through the tray icon.

Comment: Can you provide a minimalistic working example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: "it's not going into that slot" can have many different causes. Your code is not enough to recreate the problem because self.commitDataRequest is not defined amongst others.

Comment: according to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/session.html#protocols-and-support-on-different-platforms , overriding that method should be all I need to do. Anyway looks like this bug is already documented https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-33034

Answer (score 0):

You need to over ride your QtWidget:

```
    def closeEvent(self, event):

    quit_msg = "Are you sure you want to exit the program?"
    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', 
                  quit_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
    event.accept()
else:
    event.ignore()
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like same as [Prompt on exit in PyQt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414781/prompt-on-exit-in-pyqt-application).

Like you can ask to user if he/she really want to exit or not. Instead you'll show some information and then ask the question.

The answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414906/2681662

Comment: not the same use case. My app does not have a main window, its interface is through the tray icon. And I don't want to prompt the user every time a window closes.